# How to make PHP json_decode accept params in single quotes?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a list of params that I get from a specific shortcode I made available for users to provide.

Example of user input:
This is my list of names: {{names("John", 'Mike', "O'connor")}}

From that, I have a regex to extract the list of params, so I get a string like:
"John", 'Mike', "O'connor"

But now I need to convert this list to an array and the best way I can think is using json_decode, which can break as some users simply use single quotes.

What's the best way to convert this string into an array?
Using str_replace to replace ' by " will also break the ' in the "O'connor" param.

Comment: `explode(',', $string)` ?

Comment: It's not just an issue of quotes, that's not JSON at all. What definition does this format follow?

Comment: First escape the single quote's and then json_encode it

Answer (score 1):

What about extracting the names with regex like below?

```
$re = '/(["\'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1/';
$str = '{{names("John", \'Mike\', "O\'connor")}}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '"John"' (length=6)
      1 => string ''Mike'' (length=6)
      2 => string '"O'connor"' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '"' (length=1)
      1 => string ''' (length=1)
      2 => string '"' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'John' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Mike' (length=4)
      2 => string 'O'connor' (length=8)
```

The names are available at `$matches[0]`with quotes or at `$matches[2]` without quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps a lot.
Is there a easy way to use regex to also match parameters like the following?
"John", 'Mike', "The \"Rock\"", 'O\'Connor', 1000

Comment: @ThyagoTC: It seems to me, you don't have your syntax in order since you have a lot of different formats. Tell or show all formats you want to extract before I change the code and you'll request something else again.